# filling gaps inside columns and splitting columns by number

Tags: python-3.x

i have a big range of coordinate data with a high amounts of **internal column gaps** due to recording methods where 01 is recorded as 1, leaving a gap, which then separates the column in to two, so m looking to fill these gaps with zeros(**while keeping the columns as columns**) in a range of files in directory for application reading purposes.
in addition i am also trying to split the beginning of the first coordinate column that is the record number that ranges from 1 to several thousands

**Sample**:
**as you can see there are gaps inside the coordinate columns (happens every 59 seconds on the right column, but also occurs on the left column)
This has more lines on the top but thats not a problem

```
H2200 LONG. OF CENTR. MERID ...:  15 E                                          
H2401 SCALE FACTOR.............: 0.999600000                                    
H2600 NAVIGATION...............: SOURCE POSITION(S) IS ANTENNA POSITION         
H8000 EPSG GEOGRAPHIC CS NAME..: WGS84                                          
H8001 EPSG GEOGRAPHIC CS CODE..: 4326                                           
SBGR03-09       111     1382050.45S 124227.18E 299669.75753157.75115.913722 820 
SBGR03-09       111     2382049.74S 124229.53E 299726.15753181.45114.813722 841 
SBGR03-09       111     3382049.09S 124231.48E 299772.95753202.35111.813722 859 
SBGR03-09       111     4382048.43S 124233.43E 299819.75753223.55106.113722 917 
SBGR03-09       111     5382047.80S 124235.38E 299866.55753244.35100.313722 935 
SBGR03-09       111     6382047.20S 124237.32E 299913.25753264.25094.713722 953 
SBGR03-09       111     7382046.58S 124239.27E 299960.25753284.45093.7137221011 
SBGR03-09       111     8382045.93S 124241.21E 300006.75753305.35091.6137221029 
SBGR03-09       111     9382045.29S 124243.05E 300051.05753326.35084.8137221047 
SBGR03-09       111    10382044.64S 124244.85E 300094.15753347.45075.91372211 5 
SBGR03-09       111    11382043.98S 124246.69E 300138.35753369.05068.2137221123 
SBGR03-09       111    12382043.34S 124248.52E 300182.25753389.75065.5137221141 
SBGR03-09       111    13382042.69S 124250.39E 300227.25753410.95068.0137221159 
SBGR03-09       111    14382042.05S 124252.24E 300271.75753431.95062.8137221217 
SBGR03-09       111    15382041.39S 124254.11E 300316.65753453.45045.1137221235 
SBGR03-09       111    16382040.71S 124255.94E 300360.55753475.25040.2137221253 
SBGR03-09       111    17382040.04S 124257.78E 300404.65753496.92133.8137221311 
SBGR03-09       111    18382039.38S 124259.59E 300447.95753518.32324.6137221329 
SBGR03-09       111    19382038.72S 1243 1.44E 300492.55753539.94997.2137221347 
SBGR03-09       111    20382038.06S 1243 3.35E 300538.25753561.34993.61372214 5 
SBGR03-09       111    21382037.40S 1243 5.20E 300582.75753582.84985.0137221423 
SBGR03-09       111    22382036.73S 1243 7.06E 300627.55753604.74970.4137221441 
SBGR03-09       111    23382036.04S 1243 8.90E 300671.65753626.74961.5137221459 
SBGR03-09       111    24382035.37S 124310.74E 300715.65753648.74953.6137221517 
SBGR03-09       111    25382034.70S 124312.55E 300759.25753670.54933.9137221535 
SBGR03-09       111    26382034.00S 124314.41E 300803.85753693.24923.6137221553 
SBGR03-09       111    27382033.31S 124316.25E 300847.85753715.54920.3137221611 
SBGR03-09       111    28382032.64S 124318.09E 300892.25753737.34923.7137221629 .........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
.........       ...    ............ .......... ...... .........................
SBGR03-09       111  173538 316.71S 133738.39E 379569.95787233.15061.8138 64829
```

**This is how i want it to look**

```
   1 382050.45S 124227.18E
   2 382049.74S 124229.53E
   3 382049.09S 124231.48E
   4 382048.43S 124233.43E
   5 382047.80S 124235.38E
   6 382047.20S 124237.32E
   7 382046.58S 124239.27E
   8 382045.93S 124241.21E
   9 382045.29S 124243.05E
  10 382044.64S 124244.85E
  11 382043.98S 124246.69E
  12 382043.34S 124248.52E
  13 382042.69S 124250.39E
  14 382042.05S 124252.24E
  15 382041.39S 124254.11E
  16 382040.71S 124255.94E
  17 382040.04S 124257.78E
  18 382039.38S 124259.59E
  19 382038.72S 124301.44E
  20 382038.06S 124303.35E
  21 382037.40S 124305.20E
  22 382036.73S 124307.06E
  23 382036.04S 124308.90E
  24 382035.37S 124310.74E
  25 382034.70S 124312.55E
  26 382034.00S 124314.41E
  27 382033.31S 124316.25E
  28 382032.64S 124318.09E
  29 382031.97S 124319.97E
  30 382031.28S 124321.79E
  31 382030.56S 124323.66E
  32 382029.86S 124325.48E
  33 382029.21S 124327.30E
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
  .. .......... ..........
1735 38 316.71S 133738.39E
```

This is the is the cod i'll use for creating files with the three columns, (just missing the fill and the relevant split)

```
 import os


def nav2xy(target_directory, target_file):
# alines stands for after line(row deletion)
after_rows = f'alines_{target_file}.txt'

# acolumns stands for after column deletion
after_columns = f'acolumns_{target_file}.txt'

# this segment is used to remove top lines(34 in this case) for work with only the actual data
infile = open(f'{target_directory}/{target_file}', 'r').readlines()
with open(after_rows, 'w') as outfile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile):
        if index >= 34:
            outfile.write(line)

# this segment removes the necessary columns, in this case leaving only coordinates for gmt use
with open(after_rows) as In, open(after_columns, "w") as Out:
    for line in In:
        values = line.split()
        Out.write(f"{values[2]} {values[3]} {values[4]} \n")


for i in os.listdir('uko_files'):
print(i)
nav2xy('uko_files', str(i))
```

any help will be great, i have been stuck on this for a while now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming each line have the same patern it can be "sorted" by the index on the split from the spaces, taking your example this shuld work. I opted for a dictionary system to store the cordenates, i think its easyer to use.

```py
import os

# Take as a global the dir in witch is this file
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

header_lines = 5
coordinates = {}

with open('data.txt') as data_file:
    # Remove the starting lines
    for x in range(header_lines):
        data_file.readline()

    # Read everything else
    data = data_file.readlines()


# Get the important columns out
for i in data:
    x = i.split(' ')
    if x[11] == '':
        # Get the string by index
        coordinates[x[12][:1]] = [x[12][1:], x[13]]
    else:
        coordinates[x[11][:2]] = [x[11][2:], x[12]]


# Shows the 3 columns sorted
for i in coordinates:
    print(i, coordinates[i])
```

To save the sorted data as txt take as example this code.

```
# Save the data as txt #
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.txt')):
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.txt'), 'w') as file:
        for i in coordinates:
            data = str(i) + '$' + str(coordinates[i][0]) + '$' + str(coordinates[i][1]) + '$' + '\n'
            file.writelines(data)
else:
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.txt'), 'x') as file:
        for i in coordinates:
            data = str(i) + '$' + str(coordinates[i][0]) + '$' + str(coordinates[i][1]) + '$' + '\n'
            file.writelines(data)

# Read the data as txt #
read_coordenates_txt = {}
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.txt')):
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.txt')) as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        for i in data:
            x = i.split('$')
            read_coordenates_txt[x[0]] = [x[1], x[2]]

    # Shows the 3 columns sorted
    for i in read_coordenates_txt:
        print(i, read_coordenates_txt[i])
```

But i strongly recoment to use a better way to store data, such as json, like in this other example.

```
import json
# Save the data as json #
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.json')):
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.json'), 'w') as file:
        coordinates_data = json.dumps(coordinates)
        json.dump(coordinates_data, file)
else:
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.json'), 'x') as file:
        coordinates_data = json.dumps(coordinates)
        json.dump(coordinates_data, file)

# Read data as json #
read_coordenates_json = {}
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.json')):
    with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'coordinates.json')) as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)
        read_coordenates_json = json.loads(json_data)

    # Shows the 3 columns sorted
    for i in read_coordenates_json:
        print(i, read_coordenates_json[i])
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the help, but this code fills in all the gaps with zeros (maybe i can then try to make a split using E and N) which combines all the columns into one, i'm trying to keep the columns while filling the gaps inside them

Comment: Each string needs a specific lenght?

Comment: yes each on of two columns containing the coordinates will include a length of 10, while the first column (ending with an S) also comes combined with a serial number at the beginning ranging from a length of 1 to 4 as they go up(this needs to be separated to a new column)